# keyword can't be an expression in django model query

Tags: django, filter, model

I have a model with attribute start_date:

```
start_date = models.DateTimeField('Start date')
```

And a form with field

```
start_date = forms.DateField(widget= DateWidget(attrs={'id':"start_date"},usel10n = True, bootstrap_version=3, options = dateTimeOptions))
```

I'd like to filter my model by form field "start_date", so I need to check only date (start_date in form) from DateTime field in my Model. To do it I tried to derive date from DateTime in my view and compare it with Date field from form by doing this:

```
Model.objects.filter(start_date.date() = start_date)
```

and got an error:  "keyword can't be an expression", I understand why - because of:

```
start_date.date()
```

but don't know what to do with it, if I need to filter only by date part of DateTime. I also tried:

```
start_date_date
```

Got the same error

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing... What is `start_date_date.date()` supposed to be? I assume you are doing this in a view, what does your view look like?

Comment: @Ngenator Sorry for being unclear, I edited my post to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In case of `DateTimeField` to filter by date you can write something like this:

```
Model.objects.filter(
  start_date__year=dateobj.year,
  start_date__month=dateobj.month,
  start_date__day=dateobj.day
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how to use an expression as a keyword for a named argument. Do this by creating a dictionary (where you can use expressions for keys) then splat it into the method arguments:

```
kwargs = {
    start_date_date.date(): start_date
}
Model.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

But your question is not entirely clear because `start_date_date.date()` seems wrong anyway.

Comment: thank you for help, I think it will work, I edited my post to be more clear.